# Django API design

Tags: api-design, django

I recently followed the Django API tutorial. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

When I initiate a POST request my intent is that after inserting the record into database, launch a process. Example:

```
POST server/
```

Will insert a new "server" record, return 201 to API client and behind the scenes I want to launch a process that will install and discover the server via some ssh/icmp.
Where is the best place to put this code any tutorial or advise?
How can I return a 201 and after that execute my discovery process. Is it better to monitor the db for new records and have a different process doing it?

```
@csrf_exempt
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            <? is here?>
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this on the creation of a record, why not call the method as part of the view. Something like this.

```
Server_form = ServerForm(request.POST)
if server_form.is_valid():
    profile = server_form.save(commit=False) 
    profile.user = request.user
   #insert your code here to call your method

    profile.save()
```